# Centering Multiple floated divs within a container

Tags: layout, html, css-float, centering

Alright, here is a link to the site I am working on. http://danberinger.com/preview.html

I currently have the message inside its own div(#messagebox) and the picture in its own div  (#picture).  Both of these divs are floated to the left.  I put them inside a container div called #intro_container.  I would like to center this containing div, but am having trouble with it.  I have tried setting the margins to 0 and auto but that did not work.  This must be some sort of issue with the amount of different levels of divs that I am trying to work with....

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a width on your `#intro_container` container, otherwise `margin: 0 auto;` won't work.

Comment: ahh I thought that may be the issue....so I've got to calculate a width that is at least the width of the 2 divs within it and then I should be able to set the margin:0 auto;?

Comment: Yes, if it's shorter than the width of the two divs, the floated divs will just stack on top of eachother.  And if it's bigger, it'll just appear off-center. Be sure to account for any margins or padding, cause that'll add to the width.

Answer (score 0):

For 0 auto to work, you must specify a width.

You can put everything within a container div, with something like width 900px margin 0 auto, or you can simply apply these styles to intro container.

Right now your css is scaling everything to the viewport width, so float left sends the pictures to the width of intro_container, which has no defined width.

Also note, you can apply your id directly to the image!  no need to wrap that in a div.  It is good practice to style elements semantically.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's good to center things like that:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative;width:400px;height:400px;background-color:green">

  <div style="position:absolute;margin-left:50%; left: -100px; width:200px;height:200px; background-color:red">
here attribute 'left' is half of this container width
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

always working